# Converting char to std::string, then concatenating

Tags: c++, string, interface, fortran

Although I have seen many similar questions, I couldn't find a solution to this particular problematic.

My problem is very simple, yet I'm totally stuck. I have a simple c++ function, for which I tried something like

```cpp
void function1(char* filapp) {
   std::string filapp_2 = "";
   fprintf(stdout, "filapp_2: %s\n", filapp_2.c_str());
   filapp_2  += "A";
   fprintf(stdout, "filapp_2: %s\n", filapp_2.c_str());
   filapp_2  += "B";
   fprintf(stdout, "filapp_2: %s\n", filapp_2.c_str());
   filapp_2  += std::string(filapp);
   fprintf(stdout, "filapp_2: %s\n", filapp_2.c_str());
   filapp_2  += "D";
   fprintf(stdout, "filapp_2: %s\n", filapp_2.c_str());
}
```

If the input value is "C", then this code prints

```
filapp_2:
filapp_2: A
filapp_2: AB
filapp_2: ABC
filapp_2: ABC
```

I tried many other methods, still this is basically always the result. I tried prepending and it erases "AB". I don't know why that is.

It seems like when filapp is concatenate, the string is no longer dynamic and becomes constant. Maybe it related to the fact that this function is called through a fortran interface, which constrains the memory? The interface looks like

```fortran
module module_name
    implicit none
    interface
        subroutine function1 (filapp) bind(c)
            use iso_c_binding
            character(kind=c_char) :: filapp(*)
        end subroutine function1
    end interface
end module
```

EDIT:
I was asked to add the fortran part which calls the function. So I'm working on a huge, so everything is really intricate. Basically, the fortran function looks like

```fortran
call function1(filapp)
```

where filapp is defined as

```fortran
character(len=fnlen) :: filapp
```

which is different then in the interface it-self. I'm not sure what this implies.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output is ABCD

Comment: Okay, something doesn't really make sense. You should get one output line with an empty fileapp_2. I'd also test to see what filapp really is at the beginning of the method. Is it really just a char, and being forced to treat it like a pointer to somewhere you shouldn't touch? Is it a pointer to a single (not-null-terminated) character? Or is it a pointer to a null-terminated string. The only way your code is going to do what you think it should do is in the latter case. You need to find out which it is.

Comment: [I am not able to verify your results](https://wandbox.org/permlink/P27ZkNX655kWxFdc)

Comment: @JosephLarson You're right I was missing an output. About the type of variable, this is a good point. I feel like the fortran part might produce this unexpected result but I have trouble finding how.

Comment: @Ayxan That's why I'm puzzled. I think it's related to the fortran interface.

Comment: If you think it's related to the Fortran interface, then please show the Fortran code that uses the interface.

Comment: @francescalus I added some details about how the function is called.

Comment: It is allowed to associate the actual argument declared like `character(len=fnlen) :: filapp` with the dummy argument declared like `character(kind=c_char) :: filapp(*)` (if, as is likely, the default character kind is `c_char`).  However, you'd probably want to ensure that the actual argument is null-terminated in C terms (which won't happen by default).  Something like `call function1(filapp//c_null_char)` would be a good check.

Comment: @francescalus After you're answer, I checked on https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/linux_clusters/mixedProgramming2.pdf and used char(0) instead of c_null_char. It still does not work...

Comment: Possibly better would be `trim(filapp)//c_null_char` to avoid trailing blanks for clarity.

Comment: @francescalus It works! Thank you so much. Don't you want to post an official answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::string` constructor `std::string(filapp)` requires `filapp` to be null-terminated.  The actual argument in the Fortran reference to the subroutine will not be null-terminated unless you make an effort for it be be such.

Consider the example

```
use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_char, c_null_char
use module_name

call function1(c_char_'C'//c_null_char)
end
```

and look at what happens without the appended `c_null_char`.

More generally, a variable declared like

```
character(len=fnlen, kind=c_char) :: filapp
```

as a scalar character of length `fnlen` may be passed as an argument to the assumed-size dummy argument, but you'll again need to have it null-terminated:

```
call function1(TRIM(filapp)//c_null_char)
```

The trim is to avoid having trailing blanks before the termination.

Alternatively, have the null character in `filapp` by some means.